Can I count occurrences of each unique item and then sort by that count
I can easily display unique items in column A and a count of how many times they occur with =unique(A1:A100) and =countif($A$1:$A$100, B1) (assume the first formula is in B1 and the second in C1) but can I sort B and C by the count so the data is shown most common to least?
Example:



A
B
C




foo
bar
3


bar
foo
2


foo
baz
1


baz




bar




bar






You can use:
=QUERY(A2:A,"select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A order by count(A) desc label count(A) ''")

Or:
=LET(u,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A,1)),SORT({u,COUNTIF(A2:A,u)},2,))

